# Partial searches for wp_usermeta

Tags: search, user-meta

I need to perform partial searches of `wp_usermeta`, I have the following code to do the search for `wp_usermeta`, but I need you to do partial searches.

```
<form id="filtros" method="GET">
     <label for="poblacion">Poblacion:</label> <input type="text" name="poblacion">
     <label for="trabajo">Trabajos:</label> <input type="text" name="trabajo">
     <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$args = array( 
    'role' => 'empresa-BBDD',
    'meta_key' => 'poblacion',
    'meta_value' => $_GET['poblacion'],
    'meta_key' => 'categorias',
    'meta_value' => $_GET['trabajo'],
    'orderby' => 'nicename',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$usuarios = get_users( $args );

foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) {
    echo '<div class="empresa-bbdd">'; 
    echo '<h4><a href="/perfil-empresa/?id='.$usuario->ID.'">' . $usuario->user_firstname . '</a></h4>';
    echo '<p class="dir-emp"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . $usuario->calle . ', ' . $usuario->cp . ', ' . $usuario->poblacion . '</p>';
    $categorias = $usuario->categorias;
    $replace = array('[', ']', '"');
    echo '<p class="cat-emp"><b>Trabajos que realiza:</b> '. (str_replace($replace," ",$categorias)) .'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Never use unsanitized data which can be counterfeited by the user.  For example, `$_GET` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// ALWAYS sanitize user input!
$poblacion = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['poblacion'] );
$trabajo = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['trabajo'] );

$usuarios = get_users(
    array(
        'role' => 'empresa-BBDD',
        'order_by' => 'nicename',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array( // search for user meta data
            'relation' => 'AND', 
            array(
                'key'     => 'poblacion',
                'value'   => $poblacion,
                'compare' => 'LIKE' // partial comparison
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'trabajo',
                'value'   => $trabajo,
                'compare' => 'LIKE' // partial comparison
            )
        )
    )
);
```

`'relation' => 'AND'` is used to find users with both keys matching. Otherwise, use 'OR'.

`'compare' => 'LIKE'` is the same as `'%LIKE%'` in MySQL, which is to say using 'wildcards' on both ends. Search for '34' will give you '12**34**', '2**34**5' and '**34**567'.

Note! The code was not tested.

- [sanitize_text_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/)
- [get_users()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)
- [WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)